# acquiring license for Mac OS X Lion

Tags: osx-lion, license-key

We are building a software factory for producing Mobile Apps. In order to produce iPhone/iPad apps, we need a Mac OS X Lion virtual machine.
How can we buy a license for OS X Lion considering the fact that it is available only via App Store ? Can we download a ready image of the OS and purchase a license key separately ?

Comment: You must own an Apple computer in order to do this.

Comment: Also, there is no "license" per se.  At least not an alpha-numeric key.  There really is no registration process post install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically speaking the 'licence key' is essentially a chip that the operating system checks for - [apparently a TPM module](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module), though i seem to remember it might be a fan controller. Other than that there's no actual licence key as you'd find on windows.

Renan is right in saying that you'd need an apple system to run lion. There's no real legitimate workaround for it. That said, *any* mac of sufficiently recent vintage would do, so it may be worth getting a second hand mac of a supported model if cost is an issue, and upgrading it.

Answer (score 3):

Even if you want to run a Mac OS X VM, this can only legally be done on a Mac:

> With the release of Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion), Apple now allows full virtualization of its operating system, provided that it is installed on Apple hardware which is also running OS X 10.7.

(source: [VMware Knowledge Base](http://kb.vmware.com/kb/2005334))

Thus, even if you have a license, you are only allowed (according to the OS X EULA) to use it on Mac hardware. The simplest way would be buying the cheapest Mac you can find.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my dear friend, Mac osx is available only for mac machines purchased from apple. We cannot legally install it on other systems. For that you have to hackintosh it.Mac store downloads are only for apple users. To register in mac store you have to purchase a mac.

Comment: illeagal to use your software license is only in ameraca.

Answer (score 0):

The Apple license only allows for running on Apple hardware.  Hence you need a Mac.

Look for a used Mac Mini capable of running Lion.  That will most likely be the cheapest way to do that.  Also note that OS X is geared toward a single user using the machine at a time.

Comment: this to forbid use your ownership of license for restricted hardware is legal only in america.

Comment: @Kangarooo consider adding links for further reading for those interested.   Anyway, this clause has previously caused e.g. VMWare Fusion to explicitly check installation media to ensure it was a Server version.